# Weird Https / Http error in my robots.txt which relates to .htaccss file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https, robots.txt

I've set up a website, like I have done a lot of times before but getting an erorr when you actually google the site.

> clrhorizon.com/ 
>   A description for this result is not available because
>   of this site's robots.txt – learn more.

Is the message I see

If you hoover over "clrhorizon.com" this just shows a normal url which goes to the homepage.

But if you hoover over the "robots.txt" file it goes to "https://clrhorizon.com/robots.txt
Which is strange since I don't have a ssl certificate on the website which is build on wordpress.

If you then click the "robots.txt" link I get a weird error:

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://clrhorizon.systempartners.com/robots.txt"><h1><a href=http://clrhorizon.systempartners.com/robots.txt>VIEW TEMPORARY SITE</a></h1>`

And the url here isn't https anymore. 
Gone through hours of support with hosting to see where the error was but no luck. 
They suggested to clear my .robots.txt file and wait it out.

On a different thread I found a potential solution but no luck so far (read that it should update instantly).
Current .htaccess file is:

```
>     # BEGIN WordPress
> 
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
> RewriteEngine On 
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> 
> # END WordPress
```

I am loosing ideas on where the error should be.

Hope anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you submitted your site via Google Webmaster Tools as http://clrhorizon.com instead of http://www.clrhorizon.com which is what it ultimately redirects to. On the main site, you don't seem to have a robots.txt file either. Since you do have a sitemap, I would recommend creating one that looks like the following and resubmitting your site using the non-redirected domain name (include the www):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/

Sitemap: http://www.clrhorizon.com/sitemap.xml
```

My guess is that your host uses name based virtual hosting, and although you don't have an SSL cert, they are still listening on 443 for your domain and attempting to do a redirect.

You can see a description of a similar issue here http://help.bigcartel.com/questions/3221-a-description-for-this-result-is-not-available-because-of-this-site-s-robots-txt-learn-more